# What does "data" mean?

Tags: category-theory, definition

I see the word "data" from time to time in the context of category theory.
(e.g. [Glossary of category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_category_theory)
"A category consists of the following data ...")
But I've never seen the definition of "data".

Question : What does "data" mean?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *data* literally means (things which are) given

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question about mathematics.  Data has a meaning (see a dictionary) and is treated slightly differently in economics, statistics, physics, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Data means all the ingredients which constitute a category, as opposite to axioms, which describe the behavior of the given data. It is similar to when you find "Given a topological space $X$..." or "Given a function $f:A\to B$..." in a definition or a theorem. Data is what you have to consider to talk about a category, namely objects, arrows, a rule to compose two arrows together and an identity arrow for each object. This is what you need to consider to talk about categories, it is in a sense your input information. Axioms describe how this input is processed to have an actual category. For example, in an abstract group, data are the element of the group, I mean, the group itself regarded as just a set, and axioms are the axioms for a group. When the data satisfy the axioms, the set becomes a group. Similarly, when a class of objects and arrows, with a composition and identity morphisms, satisfy the axioms for a category, your data become a category.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you for your answer!